# PHP Download script with multiple connections

Tags: php, database, download, blob

I've a php code for a file download for specific user
I'm storing the content of the file in a database (using blob type).

```
<?php
//do stuffs to validate user
//do stuffs get the content from database;
//$r=mysql_fetch_object("$query");
header("Content-Type: $r->type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$r->name\"");
echo $r->content;
?>
```

In case of large files the file downloading takes long time.
How to improve the code?
Does the speed of download increased with multiple connections?

Comment: Details. Give them if you want help. What speeds are you seeing? How big is big? Over what kind of connection? etc

Comment: Can't really comment on speeding it up, but specifying the `Content-Length` header will allow the receiving user to get a status bar and estimated arrival time (may feel quicker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's no artificial limits placed on the connection, an HTTP transfer will take up as much of the network pipe as it can.

Once the connection starts getting throttled (e.g. on a file download site like Rapidshare, 'free' users get limited bandwidth), then using parallel connections MAY increase speed. e.g. a single stream is limited to 50k/s, so opening 2 streams would make for an effective 100k/s.

But then you're going to have to support ranged download. Your script as it stands sends out the entire file, from beginning to end. So the user would download the whole file twice.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably not that much you can do to speed up this specific process.

Server and client bandwidth are hard limits. Streaming the file through PHP will cause some additional overhead, but seeing as the data comes from a database, there is no straightforward way to improve that, either.

Moving to a faster server with more bandwidth may help things, but then also it might not. If the client's connection is slow, there is nothing you can do.